# Change date format of angular input with date picker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date-format

I'm very new to angular and have a label with a textbox that shows a date picker. I want the format of the input field to show the date in a format that are read from database table.

```
<label for='example'>Date</label>
<input type='text' class='form-control' date-Picker id="from" required ng-model="data.myDate" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }">
```

How can I change the format of the input text box?

Comment: which datepicker are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to filter the date according to the format that you want to show You can find information about the date and how you can format it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

1) in your controller you can do:

```
 $scope.data.myDate =  $filter('date')(new Date(), 'dd.MM.yyyy', '');
```

2) in your view:

```
{{ data.myDate | format: 'dd.MM.yyy' }}
```